# TDD Exercise: Determining User Existence

Tags: visual-studio, tdd, nunit

I'm creating a class that needs to parse user contact info to determine if the presented user already exists in the db. Because the source is unvalidated, user generated data I have to test for matches under a variety of conditions.

The content is presented in 3 fields - Name (first & last are combined); Company Name; Email

I need to return a result based on each of these possible match conditions:

> ```
> Exact Match
> Email Match
> Domain Name Only
> Full Name Exact
> Last Name Only
> Institution Match
> ```

I have a rough idea of how I'd go about coding this and am sure that the result would be inferior to what would be produced by a formal TDD approach. My TDD learning curve is just past the very basics but I don't have the depth to see how the above scenario is staged and developed thru the full lifecycle.

I'd like some help structuring the project from an architectural point of view.

thx

Comment: You seem to be on the right track... stick with it. Write a failing test first... add only the bare minimum code needed to get it to pass. Look for duplication and refactor it away. Repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like tou already listed the primary positive test cases in your list of match types. So take those from the top, write a small test for the first case (exact match), warch it fail, make it pass, iterate until exact match works. Then do the same for the other match types.

Comment: My question goes more to understanding the specifics of how create the structure of the tests themselves. Since I'm looking at a list of conditions to iterate over, I know I'll be able to reuse lots of code from one test to the next. My command of the process is such that I'd be cutting and pasting code from one test to the next. I want to get smart enough to not do that. thx

Comment: Test code is just code like any other: So just go ahead and write tests, and then refactor along the way - only refactor while all tests pass though. The refactor step in "red-green-refactor" is also about refactoring the test code.